# How to switch between switchable graphic cards in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics, amd-graphics, gpu-driver, switchable-graphics

I found this [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics) referencing this [script](https://asusm51ta-with-linux.blogspot.com/), but they have been written for Ubuntu 10, so they are outdated by now. The script doesn't seem to work, when running it under my account, it always ends with Permission denied to `/sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch` even if i manually change the ownership as instructed. Also the referenced file `/etc/init.d/rc.local` doesn't exist, so can't make the ownership permanent. Running the script with sudo doesn't show any errors, but it doesn't do anything either.

So all over again: How do i switch between integrated and discrete graphic card nowdays in Ubuntu 18.04 ?

Additional information:
distro: Kubuntu 18.04.1
kernel: 4.15
KDE: 5.12
card: AMD Radeon HD 6630M + Intel HD Graphics

Comment: Never mind. My laptop broke, so i bought a new one that has a single graphic because those constant issues with it were so damn annoying.